Horror thriller where people eat something what drain out of soil
I'm looking for the movie where:

people find the source of something white that was edible and tasty
after some time this substance started to come out of the people who ate it
the substance was white, and was gathered out of soil
English-language
1980's


The Stuff, (1985):

A delicious, mysterious goo that oozes from the earth is marketed as
  the newest dessert sensation. But the tasty treat rots more than teeth
  when zombie-like snackers who only want to consume more of the strange
  substance at any cost begin infesting the world.

